# Cannot get <span> background to work

Tags: html, css

Okay, so here's my code:

```
echo "<span style='float:right; text-align:right; background-image:url('" . $icon_url . "') no-repeat top right; height:86px; width:86px; display:block;'>" . $curr_temp . "<br />" . $curr_cond . "</span>";
```

This works perfect, with temperature and conditions displayed on the right side of the page just how I want it, but the background image will not work. When I view source in chrome I get:

```
<span style='float:right; text-align:right; background-image:url('http://forecast.weather.gov/images/wtf/medium/sct.png') no-repeat top right; height:86px; width:86px; display:block;'>35&deg;F<br />Fair</span>
```

which at least looks right to me, but if I go to inspect element (in Chrome) it shows the size of the  as 31px*40px, and the code as:

```
<span style="float:right; text-align:right; background-image:url(" http:="" forecast.weather.gov="" images="" wtf="" medium="" sct.png')="" no-repeat="" top="" right;="" height:86px;="" width:86px;="" display:block;'="">35°F<br>Fair</span>
```

which is most definitely incorrect. If I change it to be correct in the inspect element box it shows the background image fine, but still only part of it as the span stays at 31x40 instead of the 86*86 I defined it as. What am I screwing up here? I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your incredibly quick responses, everything is working now. What a great group of people you all are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element attributes should be surrounded by double quotes according to the standards. Also the `background` `url` shouldn't contain any quotes at all.

Try:

```
echo '<span style="float:right; text-align:right; background:url(' . $icon_url . ') no-repeat top right; height:86px; width:86px; display:block;">' . $curr_temp . '<br />' . $curr_cond . '</span>';
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much. I now see what everyone was saying about my single quote being what messed everything up.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems. 1) when you look at the code you're generating you're not properly using the quotes in your rule. 2) you're using the background shorthand syntax with the background-image selector.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the style attribute with single quotes, but also opening the `url` in `background-image` with single-quotes. Effectively, prematurely closing your style attribute.

Comment: The answer I marked as accepted fixed my problem, but your answer explained to me why. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a problem with your quotes. Try this:

```
echo '<span style="float:right; text-align:right; background-image:url(\'' . $icon_url . '\') no-repeat top right; height:86px; width:86px; display:block;">' . $curr_temp . '<br />' . $curr_cond . '</span>';
```

Hope it helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you need to use `background` instead of `background-image`:

```
echo "<span style='float:right; text-align:right; background:url('" . $icon_url . "') no-repeat top right; height:86px; width:86px; display:block;'>" . $curr_temp . "<br />" . $curr_cond . "</span>";
```

The only issue, there, however, is that by itself shouldn't be enough to screw up the url, just the styling. I'd look at how your $icon_url looks outside of that function to see if its generating a proper string value.

Answer (score 0):

There are some minor errors in your code (quotes and placement of text). If I'm understanding how you want your text and image to be displayed, this could do this:

```
<div style='float: right; text-align:right; 
    background-image:url("http://forecast.weather.gov/images/wtf/medium/sct.png");
    no-repeat top right; height:86px; width:86px; display:block;'>
</div>
<div style='float: right'>
    35&deg;F<br />Fair
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzT8q/2/)

If you want your text inside of your image, you can use this:

```
<span style='float:right; text-align:right; 
background-image:url("http://forecast.weather.gov/images/wtf/medium/sct.png"); 
no-repeat top right; height:86px; width:86px; display:block;'>
    35&deg;F<br />Fair
</span>
```

Hope that fixes it for you.